# Second JSON POST seems not to be executing the PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, call

So I'm getting data from the database in the first part of my jquery <-> php <-> mysql connection.

The first part works perfectly ->

My code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $( '#create-checklist' ).submit(function( event ) {
    //console.log("submit:");
        var tagList = []; // create empty (json) object
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
            if (this.checked) {
                var $this = $(this);
                tagList.push($this.attr("id"));
            }

            event.preventDefault();
        });

        var projectName = $('#insertname').val();

        var tags = JSON.stringify(tagList);
        var projectName = JSON.stringify(projectName);


        $.ajax({        
           type: "POST",
           url: "read_checkboxes.php",
           data: { tags : tags, projectName : projectName
           }, 
           success: function(result) {

               var myTags = result; 
               $('.checklist').html(myTags);
           }


      }); 

  });
```

But then I have a second Ajax call, works up to the console.log, and then doesnt seem to request update_checklist.php.

I am using #home.on because the content is generated from the first call.

```
 $( '#home' ).on( "click", ".check-todo", function() {

      var currentTodoID = [];
      var $this = $(this);

      var currentTodoID = $this.attr("id");

      var currentTodoID = JSON.stringify(currentTodoID);

      console.log(currentTodoID);


      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_checklist.php",
        data: {  currentTodoID : currentTodoID
        },
        succes: function(data) {

            var checklistData = data;

            $('.testingdiv').html(checklistData);

        }

      });

  }); 

});
```

and the php, both of the echo's are not being displayed:

This file is called update_checklist.php:

```
    if(isset($_POST["currentTodoID"])) { 

    echo 'it works'; } else {

        echo 'it doesnt work but works a bit';
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a 's' missing on ur code

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update_checklist.php",
    data: {  currentTodoID : currentTodoID
    },
    success: function(data) {//in this line

        var checklistData = data;

        $('.testingdiv').html(checklistData);

    }

  });
```

change `succes` to `success`

Comment: Almost a day of work, And I didn't see that. Thank you! I thought it had to be something with making 2 ajax calls after eachother.